# How to format a POST to create User with Basic HTTP Auth and Devise Rails Gem

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, curl, devise, basic-authentication

I'm a newb when it comes to this authenticaion business.  So I've been searching for a while, and couldn't find any straight-forward solutions:

I've got a Rails back end using the Devise gem for user auth, and an iPhone front end.  I need to know how to create a user from the iPhone.

I've got resources wrt how to create an asynchronous post, but I need to understand the general concept of HTTP authentication a bit better--if I were to, say, use Curl to create a post that would create a User utilizing basic HTTP authentication, what would be the curl command I'd send to 'www.example.com/createuser' to do so?

For this example's sake, my Rails app's user model attributes are email and password.

Thanks a million in advance for any advice/links to resources.  I very much appreciate it!

Best,
Jared

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically this is just a matter of POSTing the proper data to the user creation route (run `rake routes` to see all the routes that devise creates for you once you have it properly installed). For example, I did this with one of my apps (using command line curl):

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Accept:application/json" -d "{\"user\":{\"email\":\"jared@jared.com\", \"password\":\"super_secret_pass\", \"password_confirmation\":\"super_secret_pass\"}}" http://jared-dev/users
```

..and I get back:

```
{"status":"signed_in"}
```

..and just to confirm it worked:

```
irb(main):001:0> User.find_by_email('jared@jared.com')
=> #<User id: 2, email: "jared@jared.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$QMBAcpKjUwoC.pcRYt88a.vA0oq58jx0lagbgY298wjf...", password_salt: "$2a$10$QMBAcpKjUwoC.pcRYt88a.", reset_password_token: nil, remember_token: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 1, current_sign_in_at: "2011-03-15 19:49:47", last_sign_in_at: "2011-03-15 19:49:47", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.1.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.1.1", authentication_token: "yW37HrKUigwvSEDmXaB4", created_at: "2011-03-15 19:49:47", updated_at: "2011-03-15 19:49:47">
```

In this example, I'm posting JSON data because I think it's easier to read, but you can get curl to do standard formdata as well. I had to modify my application controller to support JSON for auth, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522069/rails-3-devise-how-to-get-devise-to-respond-with-json).

These command line options correspond to `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`, `CURLOPT_POST`, and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` set via curl_easy_setopt when using the libcurl easy interface.

Hope that helps.