# Using Devise 1.3 to authenticate JSON login requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, devise

I am new to rails. I am trying to write an API for a mobile application which authenticates using JSON. I want to use Devise for the authentication. I believe Devise >1.3 adds support for JSON as well but I cant find any examples or literature on it.

Can someone please point me to any resource for this or provide some sample code?

Thanks!
Satyam

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps this one > [http://jessehowarth.com/devise](https://web.archive.org/web/20130928040249/http://jessehowarth.com/devise)?

I plan to do the same thing in a week or two.

Comment: For the record, I ended up having a lot of trouble with Devise + JSON. I recommend using Rails 3.1 has_secure_password and adding your own custom features.

Comment: Curses! We can't find that page.

Comment: Repaired link to internet archive.

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't get to the linked page in the top answer so I thought I would add my own.
You don't need to create any custom controllers.  All you need to do is the following:

In your application.rb add the following in your application class

```
config.to_prepare do
  DeviseController.respond_to :html, :json
end
```

In config/initializers/devise.rb add `:json` to the formats.  This line is commented out by default so you will need to uncomment the line.

```
config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html, :json]
```

After this, you can send a json object to sign_in.json or whatever you have set up in your routes for sign-in.

```
{
  "user": {
    "email": "blah@blah.com",
    "password": "blah"
  }
}
```

And on success it will return 201 created, and the logged in user as a JSON object.  On error it will return 401 with a JSON message indicating the reason for failure.

Example:

```
{"error":"Invalid email or password."}
```

Here is a good example if you are using Backbone/Marionntte on the front end.

http://joshhuckabee.com/integrating-devise-backbonejs

Answer (score 4):

The Jesse Howarth's solution will break logging with browser when using html format responses. If you want to make both JSON and HTML to work try someting like this:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#new")
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    respond_to do |format|  
      format.html { respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource) }  
      format.json {  
         return render :json => {  :success => true, 
           :user => resource
         } 
      }  
    end
  end
end
```

And don't forget to change your routes to use this controller

Comment: As I commented above, roll your own if you are using Rails 3.1.0 or later.

Comment: @Tombart,   the approach works fine for correct uid/pwd json login. How to handle the case of wrong password?  the userwarden.authenticate!() will just spit out html redirect with a plain text error message.